# Returning Manager Name from AD using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to obtain the manager of the user found in AD using Excel VBA. The code is as follows:

```
Sub ADQuery()
    MsgBox GetDepartment("Simpson", "Homer")
End Sub
Function GetDepartment(strLastName As String, strFirstName As String) As String

    Dim objRoot             As Object
    Dim strDomain           As String
    Dim objConn             As Object
    Dim objComm             As Object
    Dim objRecordset        As Object

    Dim sFilter             As String
    Dim sAttribs            As String
    Dim sDepth              As String
    Dim sBase               As String
    Dim sQuery              As String


    Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDomain = objRoot.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objComm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    strLastName = Replace(strLastName, Space(1), "")
    strFirstName = Replace(strFirstName, Space(1), "")
    sFilter = "(&(objectClass=person)(objectCategory=user)(givenName=" & strFirstName & ")" & "(sn=" & strLastName & "*)" & ")"

    sAttribs = "manager,sAMAccountName,givenName,sn"
    sDepth = "SubTree"
    sBase = "<LDAP://" & strDomain & ">"
    sQuery = sBase & ";" & sFilter & ";" & sAttribs & ";" & sDepth

    objConn.Open "Data Source=Active Directory Provider;Provider=ADsDSOObject"
    Set objComm.ActiveConnection = objConn
    objComm.Properties("Page Size") = 40000
    objComm.CommandText = sQuery
    Set objRecordset = objComm.Execute

    Do Until objRecordset.EOF
       GetDepartment = objRecordset("department")
       Exit Function
       objRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop


End Function
```

But I get the following error message:

> Run-time error '3265': Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

Looking in AD itself, it seems the 'manager' attribute listed in the Attribute Editor is listed with a value:

```
CN=Burns\, Montgomery,OU=Users,OU=Springfield,OU=Nuclear Power Plant,DC=powerplantnet,DC=com
```

And the syntax is Distinguished Name.

My function returns a string and I can see that the manager attribute is not a string. How do I get the information back as a string?

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: I believe it is the line that reads: sAttribs = "manager,sAMAccountName,givenName,sn" if i put department where manager is, then it returns a value. However manager seems to be an AD attribute in itself, not a string value. Which is what I believe is causing the error

Comment: The manager attribute seems to have a link to the AD entry of the person - so I am wondering if I need to query AD with that value? I am trying to figure how to take the CN=Burns\, Montgomery,OU=Users,OU=Springfield,OU=Nuclear Power Plant,DC=powerplantnet,DC=com value and parse it to AD through my code to return the managers name, so in this case - Montgomery Burns